# I want to calculate GPS co-ordinates equally distance between the points

Tags: python, math, gps

I have the starting and ending GPS co-ordinates that form a line which is 100m long. I need to calculate the GPS co-ordinates of points equally spaces along the line i.e one is at 14m, 28m... 98m.

How would I go about calculating this?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: linear interpolation?

Comment: @DerekEden definitively....at 100 m base length no need for earth's curvature.